# Unable to access array within JSONObject after converting it to PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject and one of the properties is an array. I convert the JSONObject to a variable in PHP using:

```
 $file = file_get_contents($page);
 $jason = json_decode($file,true);
```

Where `$page` is a webpage with my JSONObject. However, when I try an access the property of my new object in PHP that had an array for the value in JSON, the value PHP spits back is just "Array". Ex:

```
$jason['address'];
```

returns just the word "Array" instead of the actual array. How can I get the actual information inside of the JSONObject's array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that `$jason['address'];` is an `array` and that cannot be echoed.

```
var_dump($jason['address']);
```

will give you that array information.

I would suggest using:

```
var_dump($jason);
```

to see the information you are really working with.

Comment: Ok, so `var_dump($jason['address']);` gets me the array that I need (thanks) but it also gets me a lot of other junk. Is there a way to get just the String array that is given?
I get this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "somestuff" }`

Comment: You would then use the array key to access that information, in your example `echo $jason['address'][0]`. [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is going to give you information about each part of the array